# Import validation plugin Error: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm trying to use jQuery validation plugin in my test app with `webpack`, when I `import` it in my file i get this error `$(...).validate is not a function`.

I know that `jquery-validation` based on IIFE and required jquery to be in global scope, which I already exposed i my config.

here it self:

```
{
    entry: {
        app: "./assets/js/app.jsx"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/build/js"),
        publicPath: "/build/js",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "bower_components"],
        alias: {
            "jquery": "jquery/dist/jquery.min",
            "jquery.validate": "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate"
        },
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx", ".es6"]
    },
    amd: {
        jQuery: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel"
            },
            {
                test: /jquery.validate/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                loader: "imports?jQuery=jquery"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            "$": "jquery",
            "jQuery": "jquery"
        })
    ],
    devtool: "source-map"
}
```

and use it like:

```
import "jquery.validate"

$("#test").validate();
```

P.S. Looks like jQuery-validation plugin is trying to use own instance of jquery, I figured out that by comparing `$.fn` in my file `[jquery: "3.1.0"]` and inside IIFE of validation plugin `[jquery: "2.2.4"]`, but how to chock up it to use my version?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you add a jqury.validate.js file before jqury.js file or after jquery.js file?

Comment: `jquery` provided as global in webpack config in `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({})` instance, so its already there

Answer (score 0):

In my setup `jquery-validate` was adding itself to it's own instance of `jquery` required from `node_modules/jquery-validation/node_modules/jquery` not the instance that exists in the ES6 app.

This seems to fix that problem:

`import 'imports-loader?define=>false,module.exports=>false!jquery-validation';`

This requires the imports-loader plugin for webpack.

`yarn add imports-loader --save-dev`

There's probably a way to configure this globally in webpack.

Answer (score -1):

```
resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "bower_components"],
        alias: {
 "jquery.validate": "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate",           
 "jquery": "jquery/dist/jquery.min"

        },
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx", ".es6"]
    },
```

Just change a position of the files.

Try this solution , i hope it works for you

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately its doesn't do the trick.